# How can we integrate Owasp ZAP & Cypress?

Tags: automation, cypress, owasp, zap

Is there any way we can integrate Owasp Zap security testing tool with Cypress?

Comment: Start Zap & then configure proxy for Cypress. See details for proxy configuration in Cypress at -  https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/proxy-configuration.html

Comment: The question is what proxy settings? How much of localhost should be ignored and what should pass through ZAP?

Answer (score 0):

I created a working demo of how this may be possible here - https://github.com/el-davo/cypress-zap.

Basically when you run "yarn test" the zap attack proxy gets started, then cypress starts and we tell it to send all its traffic through the proxy by passing this environment variable

```
HTTP_PROXY=http://localhost:8080 NO_PROXY=\"<-loopback>\"
```

Once the cypress tests have run then cypress waits for the attack proxy to complete its work, once zap has completed the tests shut down and a report is generated. Note this repo currently only works on linux but can easily be modified to work on windows